# Сложить 50 чисел как в математике

Tags: c++, математика

Сложить 50 чисел. Если сложение не удалось то написать сообщение об ошибке.
Под "не удалось" понимается, что результат не равен результату математического сложения указанных чисел.

Вот код для считывания но как сложить?

```
int x1;
int x2;
int x3;
int x4;
int x5;
int x6;
int x7;
int x8;
int x9;
int x10;
int x20;
int x30;
int x40;
int x50;
int x60;
int x70;
int x80;
int x90;
int x100;
int x200;
int x300;
int x400;
int x500;
int x600;
int x700;
int x800;
int x900;
int x1000;
int x2000;
int x3000;
int x4000;
int x5000;
int x6000;
int x7000;
int x8000;
int x9000;
int x10000;
int x20000;
int x30000;
int x40000;
int x50000;
int x60000;
int x70000;
int x80000;
int x90000;

cin >> x1;
cin >> x2;
cin >> x3;
cin >> x4;
cin >> x5;
cin >> x6;
cin >> x7;
cin >> x8;
cin >> x9;
cin >> x10;
cin >> x20;
cin >> x30;
cin >> x40;
cin >> x50;
cin >> x60;
cin >> x70;
cin >> x80;
cin >> x90;
cin >> x100;
cin >> x200;
cin >> x300;
cin >> x400;
cin >> x500;
cin >> x600;
cin >> x700;
cin >> x800;
cin >> x900;
cin >> x1000;
cin >> x2000;
cin >> x3000;
cin >> x4000;
cin >> x5000;
cin >> x6000;
cin >> x7000;
cin >> x8000;
cin >> x9000;
cin >> x10000;
cin >> x20000;
cin >> x30000;
cin >> x40000;
cin >> x50000;
cin >> x60000;
cin >> x70000;
cin >> x80000;
cin >> x90000; 

// как сложить?
```

Comment: "Слажить 50... "... "...но как сложить..." Так все таки "слажить" или "сложить"?

Comment: сложить извеняюсь я не коренной носител языка

Comment: ты про массивы слышал?

Comment: со сложением то все просто x1+x2 ... правда стоит заводить все таки массив, а не использовать отдельные переменные. А вот как вы проверите что результат не такой я не представляю. с другой стороны вы конечно можете отслеживать переполнение, это в принципе единственная ситуация когда результат будет не коррктным

Comment: цэ так но в задании про 50 чисел написана

Comment: Сказано 50 чисел, но ведь не сказано, что 50 отдельных переменных

Comment: как чтобы не было переполнение Майк?

Comment: Если вы не поленились написать 50 отдельных строчек для чтения значений этих переменных, то в чем проблема написать еще 50 отдельных строчек для их сложения?

Answer (score 4):

Как я понимаю, от вас требуется что-то типа такого:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int res = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int n, save;
        save = res;
        cin >> n;
        res += n;
        if (res < save)
        {
            cout << "Overflow!\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    cout << "Result: " << res << endl;
}
```

Comment: Думаю другой цели у этой задачи нет